# Flutter Error : [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: listview, flutter

i want to get list view from the api and put it into my app screen but it show me that

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

in my provider i added the future which i need but it has an error now and i can't run login the app

```
List<Country> _country;
List<Country> get country => _country;

Future<dynamic> countryList() async {
    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();

      http.Response  response = await http.get(Environment.country,
        headers: Environment.requestHeader);

    Map<String,dynamic> res = json.decode(response.body);
    var results;
    if (res['code'] == 200) {
      _country = [];
      res['message'].forEach((v) {
        _country.add(new Country.fromJson(v));
      });
      results = true;
    } else {
      results =
          FailedRequest(code: 400, message: res['message'], status: false);
    }
    _isLoading = false;
    notifyListeners();
    return results;
  }
```

and this is my model to class country which i use to return list

```
class Country{
  String name;
  String photo;

  Country({
    this.name,
    this.photo,
  });

  Country.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    name = json['countryName'];
    photo = json['countryImage'].toString();
  }
}
```

my json response

```
respond data : [{"countryName":"Egypt","countryImage":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/TWaReNkjTLk/maxresdefault.jpg"},{"countryName":"Canada","countryImage":"https://pix10.agoda.net/geo/country/100/3_100_canada_02.jpg?s=1920x"},{"countryName":"US","countryImage":"https://www.green-card.com/assets/Uploads/living-usa-states-florida-green-card.jpg"}]
```

i tried to add to list statement but it didn't work also !

Comment: It is good if your question has json response .

Comment: @SeaklengSay i did now

Comment: change using from json like document https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Comment: see this for advanced JSON parsing example https://stackoverflow.com/a/60224846/3756408

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is here :

`Map<String,dynamic> res = json.decode(response.body);`

Your json returned a list of maps :

`respond data : [{"countryName":"Egypt","countryImage":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/TWaReNkjTLk/maxresdefault.jpg"},{"countryName":"Canada","countryImage":"https://pix10.agoda.net/geo/country/100/3_100_canada_02.jpg?s=1920x"},{"countryName":"US","countryImage":"https://www.green-card.com/assets/Uploads/living-usa-states-florida-green-card.jpg"}]`

But, you are assigning the response which is a List to a Map.

Try changing the `Map<String,dynamic> res = json.decode(response.body);` to `List res = json.decode(response.body);`

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your response data returning a list of maps !

If you are sure that only one map (country or whatever) is there, then change your

```
Map<String,dynamic> res = json.decode(response.body);
```

to

```
Map<String,dynamic> res = json.decode(response.body)[0];
```

If there are num of maps (countries or whatever), then change your

```
Map<String,dynamic> res = json.decode(response.body);
```

to

```
List<Map<String,dynamic>> res = json.decode(response.body);
```