# read data from Map<String, Object>

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I get these type of data from some api. I want to read data from "FK_User" which seems an object, when 
I read data like this i get this error:

> The method '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.
>    - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
>     print(a["FK_User"]["username"]);

and the data is like this:

```
var a = {
    "ID": "dummyID",
    "FK_User": {
        "username": "dummyID",
    },
    "Somefield": "dymmy",

}

var b = a["FK_User"]["username"];
```

how can I read this type of data?

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60224846/3756408

Comment: print((a["FK_User"] as Map)["username"]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Map<String, dynamic> a = {
  "ID": "dummyID",
  "FK_User": {
    "username": "dummyID",
  },
  "Somefield": "dymmy",
};

var b = a["FK_User"]["username"]; // dummyID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String,dynamic> a_map = Map.castFrom(a);
Map<String,dynamic> fk_user_map = Map.castFrom(a_map["FK_user"]);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.