# How can I get string value from API in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get *string value from the API* to the list in a *flutter*.

Each time I try to get the list there is an **exception "Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map'"**

the data I have is in the format given below:

```
{
"status": 1,
"data": [
        "Chapter 1",
        "Chapter 2",
        ]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you edit your question and show us your code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60224846/3756408

Answer (score 0):

Use this response class to load response and access all the variables.

```
 class ResponseData {
        String status;
        List<String> data;

        ResponseData({
            this.status,
            this.data,
        });

        factory ResponseData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ResponseData(
            status: json["status"],
            data: List<String>.from(json["data"].map((x) => x)),
        );
    }
```

Add our response json to ResponseData class

```
ResponseData responseDataFromJson(String responseFromServiceCall) => ResponseData.fromJson(json.decode(responseFromServiceCall));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it is still giving an error "[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast"

Answer (score 0):

From the above mentioned json i have created a sample json  for ListView :

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "data": [
        "Chapter 1",
        "Chapter 2"
    ]
}
```

Creating a model class from the json :

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final data = dataFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Data dataFromJson(String str) => Data.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String dataToJson(Data data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Data {
    int status;
    List<String> data;

    Data({
        this.status,
        this.data,
    });

    factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
        status: json["status"],
        data: List<String>.from(json["data"].map((x) => x)),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "status": status,
        "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x)),
    };
}
```

Parsing data and then rendering it on ui :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import 'dummy.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<String> dataList = List();
  bool _isLoading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadYourData();
  }

  Future<String> loadFromAssets() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('json/parse.json');
  }

  loadYourData() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    String jsonString = await loadFromAssets();
    final data = dataFromJson(jsonString);
    // here you get the complete object
    dataList = data.data;
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: _isLoading
              ? CircularProgressIndicator()
              : ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: dataList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Card(
                      child: Column(

                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text(dataList[index]),
                          ),

                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Following is the parse.json file :

[image]

And below is the pubspec file where you need to define the json folder :

[image]
Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it is still giving an error "[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: json/parse.json"

Comment: because you have to add the JSON folder and create the parse.json file inside it, and later you have to define your JSON folder in the pubspec.yaml file. for you, I have edited the post and added the screenshots.